# is it appropriate to use "quinquennial" in academic writing?

Tags: word-choice

I'm conflicted about the trade off between accessibility and conciseness when deciding whether or not to use "quinquennial" in an article for an academic journal. Is it advisable to use another word to avoid sounding pretentious?

My use case is the description of survey periods - there is an annual survey and a quinquennial survey.

Comment: Which journal (what is the subject of your paper?) If it's an academic journal, you might get away with it - it's a good word - if it's appropriate to the subject.)

Comment: What @Susan said. Effectively, the question is POB, since everything depends on the *specific* publication. It's much more likely to be acceptable in an ecclesiastical journal than one concerned with computer science, for example.

Comment: It is a scientific journal titled "Remote Sensing of Environment".

Comment: Yes, if it's pertinent to your research, that journal is sufficiently academic and technological to accept that word without question.

Comment: But if you're worried about sounding pretentious, don't use it anywhere near your username here. Try 'Dawn Redwood'.

Comment: If we can't be pretentious in academic journals, where can we be? Such journals are among the few places where one can reasonably expect a certain level of erudition among the readers. I say use the word that best expresses your meaning.

Comment: In case people wish to know: happening every _five_ years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dealing with different periods, and the quinquennial case is particularly common among the set of periods found, or of particular interest, then it would be the ideal word to use.

If you've got uses of the more common *-ennial* words, and you've also got a quinquennial case, then use.

Otherwise, it's "appropriate" in that it is an English word that means what you want (well, assuming you are actually using it correctly, rather than e.g. to mean the colour of elephant hide or something), but it's not likely to be a *good* use.

Comment: Or perhaps it meant "vaguely bitter tasting"?